# Connect 4 Javascript/jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having issues with my js/jquery code for my connect 4 game.  Any advice would be appreciated.  This is for a project for a web dev 100 bootcamp I am currently in.

```
// Jquery and Javascript for Connect4
$(document).ready(function() {
    var config = {
        blackPlayer: "Player 1",
        redPlayer: "Player 2",
        startingPlayer: "blackPlayer",
    };
    var currentPlayer = config.startingPlayer;
    // Function to change player
    function changePlayer() {
    if (currentPlayer === 'black') {
        currentPlayer = 'red';
    } else {
        currentPlayer = 'black';
    };
    };
    // Empty board 
    var state = [[],
                 [],
                 [],
                 [],
                 [],
                 [],
                 []];
        // trigger the game by clicking on a position on the board
        $(".col-1").on('click', function(e) {
            var $col = $(e.currentTarget);
            var colindex = $col.index();
            state[colindex].push(currentPlayer);
            var colarray= state[colindex];
            for (var i=0; i<colarray.length; i++);
                var $cell= $col.find('.cell').get(5-i);
                $('cell').addClass('currentPlayer');
    });
});
```

markup

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <title>Connect 4!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Connect 4!</h1>
    <!-- Try and make player icon switch (p1,p1, black,red) every time a button in column is clicked -->
        <h2>
            <span>Current Player is: </span>
            <span class="changeplayer">Player 1</span>
        </h2>
<!-- Start of Board -->

    <div class="col-container">
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-1">
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>
          <div class="cell"></div>

       </div>


    </div>

    <h3>Created by Kevin Lawler</h3>

</body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: More information about what your exact issue is would be helpful; One thing I see at initial glance is your `config` object has the `startingPlayer` property set to `'blackPlayer'`, and in your `changePlayer` function, you are testing for `'black'`, not `'blackPlayer'`

Comment: thanks @R.Smith.  That helped.  my codes working now

Comment: semi-colon on end of this line is syntax error: `for (var i=0; i<colarray.length; i++);`

Answer (score 0):

updated JS

```
var config = {
    blackPlayer: "Player 1",
    redPlayer: "Player 2",
    startingPlayer: "blackPlayer",
};

var currentPlayer = config.startingPlayer;

// Function to change player

function changePlayer() {
    if (currentPlayer === 'blackPlayer') {
        currentPlayer = 'redPlayer';
    } else {
        currentPlayer = 'blackPlayer';
    };
};
```